# Thevenin Impedance

Tags: thevenin, impedance-matching

If neither open-circuit voltage nor short-circuit current is zero, can we always find the Thevenin impedance by dividing open-circuit voltage by short-circuit current? Under what condition (in addition to voc = isc = 0) we can not do this?

Comment: Is this a homework?

Comment: I'm unclear as to what you're asking. "Dividing the open-circuit voltage by short-circuit current" doesn't sound like any method I've used to calculate Thevenin impedance...

Comment: @AsaGraf That is the standard method, assuming a multimeter is the only equipment available to you.  There are more accurate methods if you have additional equipment.

Comment: You are right - I was just having trouble understanding the wording of the question.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to point out that Thevenin's theorem only works for linear circuits. If you have a non-linear network, then the open circuit voltage and the short circuit current won't give you any information about other operating points.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that. For example let's consider the following circuit:

[image]

Here if we are asked to find thevenin impedence looking from AB then in a normal way:

1. We first short circuit the voltage supply.
2. Then equivalent resistance is : 1 ohm || 1 ohm = 0.5 ohm

However going by your method:

1. Open circuit voltage = 5 volts
2. Short circuit current = 10 / 1 = 10 ampere
3. Voc / Isc = 5 / 10 = 0.5 ohm

Thus we get the same answer in both cases.